# How to get tommorow date using cat Bash?

Tags: bash

I know I can do:

```
cat <<EOF
Now is $(date "+%B %d, %Y")
EOF
```

Which gives:

```
Now is August 04, 2023
```

What I want to get is:

```
Now is August 04, 2023 17:40 UTC
Tomorrow is August 05, 2023 17:40 UTC
```

I tried

```
cat <<EOF
Now is $(date "+%B %d, %Y, %H:%s") UTC
Tomorrow is $(date -d "+%B %d, %Y %H:%s" '+1 day') UTC
EOF
```

but this doesn't work.. it doesn't even show error message

Comment: The `+1 day` argument has to go immediately after `-d`.

Comment: `date -d tomorrow "+%B %d, %Y %H:%s"`

Comment: You sure you don't get an error? I get `date: invalid date ‘+%B %d, %Y %H:%s’`

Comment: Which operating system are you on? `date` isn't part of bash, it's a separate command provided by your OS; so we need to know your OS to know how `date` works for you.

Comment: I'm on Mac OS @CharlesDuffy

Comment: Ah. A lot of the fancy things you've seen people do are only for GNU Date, which comes with Linux, not with MacOS.

Comment: Since you're on MacOS -- have you installed a modern version of bash, as with NixOS or MacPorts or Homebrew, or do you still have the more-than-a-decade-old GPLv2 release Apple ships?

Comment: did you try running `date -d "+%B %d, %Y %H:%s" '+1 day'` at the command prompt?

Comment: (if you've installed a modern bash, you can use the `printf %(...)T` approach given in my answer and not need to care about `date` at all).

Comment: @markp-fuso is there a way to make this in UTC rather than in my local time zone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using below

```bash
cat <<EOF
Now is $(date "+%B %d, %Y, %H:%s") UTC
Tomorrow is $(date -v+1d "+%B %d, %Y %H:%s" ) UTC
EOF
```

Here `-v+1d` argument tells `date` to add 1 day to the current date.

Comment: Is there a way for the timestamp to be always in UTC rather than in my local Mac OS timezone?

Comment: @Luis, as with all things `date` it depends on your OS vendor's implementation, but usually you can set `TZ=UTC` in the environment. Put it directly before the date command with no separator -- `TZ=UTC date ...` -- to export only for the duration of that one command's invocation.

Answer (score 1):

`date` isn't  part of bash, so bash can't control how it works for your OS. How `date` works for you is up to Apple, or Red Hat, or Ubuntu, or FreeBSD, or whoever else your OS vendor happens to be.

Consider instead using the time functionality that **is** built in to bash (note that this was introduced in the 4.x series, and isn't available on the ancient bash 3.2 that Apple ships by default):

```
printf -v now_epoch '%(%s)T' -1
printf 'Now is %(%B %d, %Y)T\n' "$now_epoch"
printf 'Tomorrow is %(%B %d, %Y)T\n' "$(( now_epoch + (60 * 60 * 24) ))"
```

---

Of course you can embed this in a heredoc like anything else if you want `cat` to be between the shell-builtin `printf` and your stdout:

```
cat <<EOF
$(printf -v now_epoch '%(%s)T' -1
  printf 'Now is %(%B %d, %Y)T\n' "$now_epoch"
  printf 'Tomorrow is %(%B %d, %Y)T\n' "$(( now_epoch + (60 * 60 * 24) ))")
EOF
```

...though why it would make any sense to do so is beyond my comprehension.